# Run async methods in paralell from non async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How do I call async methods in paralell from a non async method? I also need to catch exceptions an log them in the calling method.

The implementation below works, but I have read that WaitAny is not recommended, but I have not been able to make it work with for example WhenAll.

Ps, the "real" async methods in my app may take quite a long time to finish, around 10 mins.

```
class AsyncTest
{

   public void RunAsyncInParalell()
   {
       var tasks = new List<Task>();

       var count = 500;

       for(var i=0; i<count;i++ )
       {
          tasks.Add(AsyncMethod(i));    
        }

        while (tasks.Count() > 0)
        {
            var index = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
            try
            {
                var res = tasks[index].Exception;
                if (res != null)
                {
                    res.Flatten();

                    foreach (Exception ex in res.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: "+ ex.Message, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {

                aex = aex.Flatten();

                foreach (Exception ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message, ex);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
            tasks.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }


    public async Task<int> AsyncMethod(int i)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        int ticks = rnd.Next(0, 5000);
        if (i == 50)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception thrown for i=" + i);
        }
        await Task.Delay(ticks);
        return (i);
    }
}
```

Comment: *How do I call async methods in paralell from a non async method?* Is there any reason you're trying to do this? I'm assuming you can't alter the calling method?

Comment: Why not wrap `Tasks.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())` in a try/catch block, I think that works.

Comment: IMHO I would suggest donot mix the sync and async code

Comment: This would bring result of completed task `while(tasks.Any()) { var completed = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);tasks.Remove(completed);`

Comment: @Eldho: I know that I should not mix async and non async code, but I cannot change the signature of the calling method.

Comment: @Eldho: No that does not work as the await operator requires the method to have an async modifer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, but nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: `AsyncMethod` can also throw - if that happens before the first `await`, you're going to get an exception on `tasks.Add(AsyncMethod(i));` - that also has to be covered. If `WaitAll` doesn't work, you need to figure out *why* that happens - are you having a deadlock or something? And in any case, `Task.WhenAll(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is probably a better idea anyway, if you really have to block. You don't even have to use `WhenAll`, really - just call it on each of the tasks in sequence. You can even use LINQ to get an array of results :)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I call async methods in parallel from a non async method?

The best answer is "you don't". You can, however, call asynchronous methods concurrently *from another asynchronous method*:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  var count = 500;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    tasks.Add(CallMethodAsync(i));

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task CallMethodAsync(int i)
{
  try
  {
    await AsyncMethod(i);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: "+ ex.Message, ex);
    throw; // TODO: Decide if this is the behavior you want.
  }
}
```

The correct way to call `RunAsync` is with `await`. If you can't make the calling code async, then first check out my blog series on [how to make asynchronous code play well with OOP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html). If you still can't make the calling code async, then check out the various [dubious hacks for mixing asynchronous and synchronous code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) in my MSDN brownfield async article.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronously wait for all tasks to complete, beware of the context : use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on each awaited task or wait on a thread that doesn't hold the context.

You can use [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
// Then iterate over tasks to get results
```